# What is the difference between . and .data?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm trying to develop a deeper understanding of using the dot (".") with `dplyr` and using the `.data` pronoun with `dplyr`. The code I was writing that motivated this post, looked something like this:

```
cat_table <- tibble(
  variable = vector("character"), 
  category = vector("numeric"), 
  n        = vector("numeric")
) 

for(i in c("cyl", "vs", "am")) {
  cat_stats <- mtcars %>% 
    count(.data[[i]]) %>% 
    mutate(variable = names(.)[1]) %>%
    rename(category = 1)
  
  cat_table <- bind_rows(cat_table, cat_stats)
}
```

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  variable category     n
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 cyl             4    11
2 cyl             6     7
3 cyl             8    14
4 vs              0    18
5 vs              1    14
6 am              0    19
7 am              1    13
```

The code does what I wanted it to do and isn’t really the focus of this question. I was just providing it for context.

I'm trying to develop a deeper understanding of *why* it does what I want it to do. And more specifically, why I can't use `.` and `.data` interchangeably. I've read the [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) article, but I guess in my mind, both `.` and `.data` just mean "our result up to this point in the pipeline." But, it appears as though I'm oversimplifying my mental model of how they work because I get an error when I use `.data` inside of `names()` below:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(.data[["cyl"]]) %>% 
  mutate(variable = names(.data)[1])
```

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `variable`.
x Can't take the `names()` of the `.data` pronoun
ℹ Input `variable` is `names(.data)[1]`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

And I get an unexpected (to me) result when I use `.` inside of `count()`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(.[["cyl"]]) %>% 
  mutate(variable = names(.)[1])
```

```
  .[["cyl"]]  n   variable
1          4 11 .[["cyl"]]
2          6  7 .[["cyl"]]
3          8 14 .[["cyl"]]
```

I suspect it has something to do with, "Note that .data is not a data frame; it’s a special construct, a pronoun, that allows you to access the current variables either directly, with .data$x or indirectly with .data[[var]]. Don’t expect other functions to work with it," from the *Programming with dplyr* article. This tells me what `.data` *isn't* -- a data frame -- but, I'm still not sure what `.data` *is* and how it differs from `.`.

I tried figuring it out like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
  count(.data[["cyl"]]) %>% 
  mutate(variable = list(.data))
```

But, the result `<S3: rlang_data_pronoun>` doesn't mean anything to me that helps me understand. If anybody out there has a better grasp on this, I would appreciate a brief lesson. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Up front, I think `.data`'s intent is a little confusing until one also considers its sibling pronoun, `.env`.

The dot `.` is something that `magrittr::%>%` sets up and uses; since `dplyr` re-exports it, it's there. And whenever you reference it, it is a real object, so `names(.)`, `nrow(.)`, etc all work as expected. It *does* reflect data up to this point in the pipeline.

`.data`, on the other hand, is defined within `rlang` for the purpose of disambiguating symbol resolution. Along with `.env`, it allows you to be perfectly clear on where you want a particular symbol resolved (when ambiguity is expected). From [`?.data`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html), I think this is a clarifying contrast:

```r
disp <- 10
mtcars %>% mutate(disp = .data$disp * .env$disp)
mtcars %>% mutate(disp = disp * disp)
```

However, as stated in the help pages, `.data` (and `.env`) is just a "pronoun" (we have verbs, so now we have pronouns too), so it is just a pointer to explain to the tidy internals where the symbol should be resolved. It's just a hint of sorts.

So your statement

> *both `.` and `.data` just mean "our result up to this point in the pipeline."*

is not correct: `.` represents the data up to this point, `.data` is just a declarative hint to the internals.

---

Consider another way of thinking about `.data`: let's say we have two functions that completely disambiguate the environment a symbol is referenced against:

- `get_internally`, this symbol must always reference a column name, it will not reach out to the enclosing environment if the column does not exist; and
- `get_externally`, this symbol must always reference a variable/object in the enclosing environment, it will never match a column.

In that case, translating the above examples, one might use

```r
disp <- 10
mtcars %>%
  mutate(disp = get_internally(disp) * get_externally(disp))
```

In that case, it seems more obvious that `get_internally` is not a frame, so you can't call `names(get_internally)` and expect it to do something meaningful (other than `NULL`). It'd be like `names(mutate)`.

So don't think of `.data` as an object, think of it as a mechanism to disambiguate the environment of the symbol. I think the `$` it uses is both terse/easy-to-use and absolutely-misleading: it is not a `list`-like or `environment`-like object, even if it is being treated as such.

BTW: one can write any S3 method for `$` that makes any classed-object look like a frame/environment:

```r
`$.quux` <- function(x, nm) paste0("hello, ", nm, "!")
obj <- structure(0, class = "quux")
obj$r2evans
# [1] "hello, r2evans!"
names(obj)
# NULL
```

(The presence of a `$` accessor does not always mean the object is a frame/env.)

Comment: Thank you, @r2evans. But, I'm still not 100% sure why the mutate(variable = names(.data)[1]) throws an error. Any insight on that?

Comment: Thank you again. I'm still not sure that I've completely absorbed this. But, I'm much closer than I was.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I *want* `.data` to reference the current-data, similar to `data.table`'s `.SD` reference. But alas, it is not.

Comment: "why names(.data) throws an error." That is because `.data` is not a data frame but an environment (see my answer). @r2evans Nice answer but I think it is missing the crucial point that `.data` always represents the _current_ data. In particular, it represents data for the current group, not the entire data frame, and it will also contain new columns created in previous expressions.

Comment: @LionelHenry, thank you for piping in! I recognize that you are `c("aut", "cre")` for `rlang`, there is no refuting your knowledge on the subject. However, `names(env)` and `length(env)` both work on environments but don't work on .data, so perhaps calling it an environment can be misinterpreted?

Comment: More precisely, it has the data structure of an environment (a chain of environments actually) rather than a data frame. This is a pronoun with its own accessor methods which _represents_ an environment.

Comment: Very interesting. Next time I have free time (ugh), I'll look into the implementation. I understand what you're saying but not sure why (1) a chain of environments is necessary to similar the namespace of a single frame/environment, and (2) why it would not support `environment`-friendly functions. Not meaning to distract from this topic, I'll look and pipe up elsewhere if I really have questions about it. Thanks, @LionelHenry!

Comment: Regarding (1), it's because the lower level contains special bindings for tidy eval. And in some more complicated cases (tidyselect) we store functions in an upper level and data in a lower level. Regarding (2) we did it on purpose because environments are by nature unordered, unlike data frames. Allowing `names()` would be confusing and cause programming errors.

Answer (score 3):

The `.` variable comes from `magrittr`, and is related to pipes.  It means "the value being piped into this expression".  Normally with pipes, the value from a previous expression becomes argument 1 in the next expression, but this gives you a way to use it in some other argument.

The `.data` object is special to `dplyr` (though it is implemented in the `rlang` package).  It does not have any useful value itself, but when evaluated in the `dplyr` "tidy eval" framework, it acts in many ways as though it is the value of the dataframe/tibble.  You use it when there's ambiguity:  if you have a variable with the same name `foo` as a dataframe column, then `.data$foo` says it is the column you want (and will give an error if it's not found, unlike `data$foo` which will give `NULL`).  You could alternatively use `.env$foo`, to say to ignore the column and take the variable from the calling environment.

Both `.data` and `.env` are specific to `dplyr` functions and others using the same special evaluation scheme, whereas `.` is a regular variable and can be used in any function.

Edited to add:  You asked why `names(.data)` didn't work.  If @r2evans excellent answer isn't enough, here's a different take on it: I suspect the issue is that `names()` isn't a `dplyr` function, even though `names.rlang_fake_data_pronoun` is a method in `rlang`. So the expression `names(.data)` is evaluated using regular evaluation instead of tidy evaluation. The method has no idea what dataframe to look in, because in that context there isn't one.

Comment: Thank you, @user2554330. But, I'm still not 100% sure why the mutate(variable = names(.data)[1]) throws an error. Any insight on that?

Comment: See the addition.

Comment: Nice context. Your last paragraph suggests that if they implemented (say) `names.rlang_fake_data_pronoun`, they might be able to get *that* function to work. (It still doesn't address my *itch* to use `.data` like I do `.SD` ... :-)

Comment: Actually there is a `names.rlang_fake_data_pronoun` method:  it's what prints the error message.  It can't do anything else, because it's being evaluated in the regular R evaluation scheme, not tidy eval.  Tidy eval has access to lots of `dplyr`-specific information.

Answer (score 3):

On a theoretical level:

`.` is the magrittr pronoun. It represents the entire input (often a data frame when used with dplyr) that is piped in with `%>%`.

`.data` is the tidy eval pronoun. Technically it is not a data frame at all, it is an evaluation environment.

On a practical level:

`.` will never be modified by dplyr. It remains constant until the next piped expression is reached. On the other hand, `.data` is always up to date. That means you can refer to previously created variables:

```r
mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    cyl2 = cyl + 1,
    am3 = .data[["cyl2"]] + 10
  )
```

And you can also refer to column *slices* in the case of a grouped data frame:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(cyl2 = .data[["cyl"]] + 1)
```

If you use `.[["cyl"]]` instead, the entire data frame will be subsetted and you will get an error because the input size is not the same as the group slice size. Tricky!

Answer (score 2):

Compare `mtcars %>% count(.data[["cyl"]])` vs. `mtcars %>% count(.[["cyl"]])`.

```
mtcars %>% count(.[["cyl"]])
  .[["cyl"]]  n
1          4 11
2          6  7
3          8 14


mtcars %>% count(.data[["cyl"]])
  cyl  n
1   4 11
2   6  7
3   8 14
```

`.` is literally just the previous result. So the first is similar to:

```
. <- mtcars
count(., .[["cyl"]])
```

The second is a shorthand for looking up the variable by the string "cyl" and treating the previous result as the search path for the variable. For example, suppose you mispelled your variable name:

```
mtcars %>% count(.[["cyll"]])
   n
1 32

mtcars %>% count(.data[["cyll"]])
Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `cyll` is not found.
```

Using `.` will not throw an error because indexing to a non-existing column is a valid base-R operation that returns `NULL`.

Using `.data` will throw because using a non-existent variable:

```
mtcars %>% count(cyll)
```

Also throws.

Comment: Thank you, @thc. But, I'm still not 100% sure why the mutate(variable = names(.data)[1]) throws an error. Any insight on that?

Comment: @BradCannell Because `.data` is not an object and is never evaluated internally. It's simply a keyword (they call it pronoun) that provides a way of accessing columns using bracket `[[` or `$` notation.  The key concept is "lazy evaluation". The arguments in a function in R are not evaluated until you use them, and there are many ways to see the arguments without evaluation. Internally, `.data` is never used as an object. It's simply seen as an argument that directs the function to do certain things.